# how to write a selector contain [ and ] in the tag name attribute in jquery

Tags: jquery

I wanna to detect an input tag that its name is: **some[en]** in jquery. I write this selector but it doesn't work:

```
$("input[name=some\[en\]]")
```

how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting it in `'`

```
$("input[name='some[en]']")
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kVsTe/

This is the preferred way for all attribute selectors.

Answer (score 1):

Escape rules for special characters in selectors outline use of double backslash for escaping. ALso best to follow quoting of attribute value as shown in API

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

```
 $("input[name='some\\[en\\]']")
```

Comment: @DanielA.White - just following API docs. Yes it works without in current version but not documented and possibly not backward compatible